# Pandas .loc subsetting method with multiindexes

Tags: python, pandas

Given the DataFrame, di, created here:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "Event": ['Biathlon', 'Ski Jump', 'Slalom', 'Downhill'],
    "Award": ['Gold', 'Bronze', 'Gold', 'Silver'],
    "Points":  ['100', '10', '100', '40']
}
d = pd.DataFrame(data)
di = d.set_index(["Award","Event"])
```

Why does this execute without an issue

```
di.loc['Gold','Biathlon',:]
```

while this

```
di.loc['Gold','Biathlon','Points']
```

raises an error?

---

UPDATE: 2/29

After some digging in the docs, it seems to me that

```
di.loc['Gold','Biathlon',:]
```

is not really supported syntax at all despite appearing to work in the example above. While investigating MultiIndexes, I came across a [note describing the importance of using the sort_index()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#the-need-for-sortedness-with-multiindex) on DataFrames with Multiindexes in cases where the user is trying to use slices. When I sort the index in di above, the above statement now throws an error. This suggests to me that using three selection arguments in the way I've done here is not supported. This would make sense as it could be interpreted ambiguously.

e.g.

```
di_isorted = di.sort_index()
di_isorted.loc['Gold','Biathlon',:] #now throws an error
```

Comment: `Points` is the title of a data series, not something that has a location. So `['Gold','Biathlon','100'] ` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your dataframe, which has a MultiIndex:

```
                Points
Award  Event          
Gold   Biathlon    100
Bronze Ski Jump     10
Gold   Slalom      100
Silver Downhill     40
```

When you use `.loc` on a dataframe, it is generally a rows, columns selection (i.e. `df.loc[row_indexer, column_indexer]`).  So in your case, you are selecting the row with 'Gold' and 'Biathlon' in the index, and the ':' signifies all of the columns.

```
>>> di.loc['Gold','Biathlon', :]
               Points
Award Event          
Gold  Biathlon    100
```

Note that the results will be returned as a series if you pass the argument as a tuple:

```
>>> di.loc[('Gold','Biathlon'), :]
Points    100
Name: (Gold, Biathlon), dtype: object
```

Trying to use `.loc` with your syntax (`di.loc['Gold','Biathlon','Points']`) results in an error because you only have two levels in your MultiIndex whereas you are requesting three.

> KeyError: 'Key length (3) exceeds index depth (2)'

When using `loc` on a dataframe, a single argument will result a cross section of the data at that index point and thus return a Series.

```
# or di.loc['Gold', 'Biathlon']
>>> di.loc[('Gold', 'Biathlon')]
Points    100
Name: (Gold, Biathlon), dtype: object
```

So using the row, column selection criteria, you are specifying a single cell in the dataframe given your selection criteria.

```
>>> di.loc[('Gold', 'Biathlon'), 'Points']
'100'
```

This is equivalent to getting the data `at` that location.

```
>>> di.at[('Gold', 'Biathlon'), 'Points']
'100'
```

See the docs for more information on how to use `loc` and on [Indexing and Selecting Data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-and-selecting-data).

Comment: I guess I'm a little puzzled by the fact that including a slicer (e.g. di.loc['Gold', 'Biathlon', :]) indicates to select based on columns while including a column label (e.g. di.loc['Gold', 'Biathlon', 'Points'] causes an error. Per the documentation, aren't both single labels and slicers valid arguments to .loc[]?